# How can I exit php upon error with a custom html message

Tags: php, html, exit, die

I am wondering what is the best way I can exit a php script (if I encounter an error) where I also include all my html code too. Currenty my script is:

```
<?php

    // Some other code here

    // These if statements are my error handling
    if(!isset($var)) {
        $message = 'Var is not set'
        exit('<title>Error Page</title>'.$message.'<footer>Test Footer</foot>');
    }

    if($a != $b) {
        $message = 'a is not equal to b';
        exit('<title>Error Page</title>'.$message.'<footer>Test Footer</foot>');
    }

    $success = 'YAY, we made it to the end';
?>

<html>
    <header>
        <title>YAY</title>
        <!-- Other stuff here -->
    </header>
    <!-- Other stuff here -->
    <body>
    <!-- Other stuff here -->
    <?php echo $success ?>
    <!-- Other stuff here -->
    </body>
    <!-- Other stuff here -->
    <footer>The best footer</footer>
</html>
```

You can see my exit message has bad style (since I am cramming all my html there). Is there a way where I can have a nice html error page to show with the custom message.

Comment: But why would you exit your script at all? As I can see you run it in the context of HTML, so you should almost never terminate the script with an exit

Comment: @Dharman Well this is a sample script, but the purpose of exit is because we encountered an error, so I want to exit and show a nice html formatted error message. What is your suggestion on handling errors?

Comment: Do you still want to print the bottom html part? if no then you can `echo "your html code"; exit();` inside the `if`.

Comment: @catcon They are sample if statements. In my actual code (which is longer), it has different if statements (which do error handling properly). I didn't want to post long code because that's not the question I am asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a html page that has the template and then use the `str_replace` function to replace a keyword in the html page. In this case the word we are replacing with your error message is `{message}`.

**error_page_template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Error Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        {message}

    </body>
</html>
```

---

**script.php**

```
<?php

    function error_page($message) {
        $htmlTemplate = file_get_contents('error_page_template.html');
        $errorPage = str_replace('{message}', $message, $htmlTemplate);
        return $errorPage;
    }

    echo error_page('An error has occurred');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of this but this is what I basically wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am linking to another file on script failure that takes your defined message and prints it as clean HTML5 that can be styles at will.

I think this is your best option (script utilizes a file that you must include on error):

```
<?php
//On failure (this is the error)
$message = 'Error message';
//I can use a variable inside double quotes because they do not take the string
//literally, if it were single quotes it would take the string as a literal and it
//would print $message as $message
//The `die()` function kills the script and executes whatever you put inside of it.

die(require "e_include.php");
?>
```

Then there is the other file (that is being linked to):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>YAY</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <p><?php echo $message ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```